# Flex 4: Title window goes out of accessible area

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, flex4, popup

I have a strange issue- I use a title window to create a message to the user. The user has the ability to move the title window around the screen so that the main screen is visible.

However if the user were to move the title window way too much, it can actually go outside the browser accessible area- the user has no option but to close the browser and start again. How do we ensure that the title window movement is limited, such that the title bar is always available for control?

I might not have worded this right- pls check the attached image[image: image going out of screen].

Answer (score 4):

I'd listen to the [move](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event%3amove) event of the TitleWindow.  If the window is moved out of the visible coordinates of the application, move it back.

If you're only issue is w/ allowing the users to closet the window, then you could add a "Close" button on the bottom of the window in addition to the 'x' at the top.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a custom component I'd suggest you override the TitleWindow's move() method. I'm using the following code to restrict the window movement:

```
public class PopUpWindow extends TitleWindow
{
    private static const MIN_VISIBLE:int = 50;

    public override function move(x:Number, y:Number):void
    {
        var maxX:Number = stage.stageWidth - MIN_VISIBLE;
        var maxY:Number = stage.stageHeight - MIN_VISIBLE;

        if (x < 0)
            x = 0;
        else if (x > maxX)
            x = maxX;

        if (y < 0)
            y = 0;
        else if (y > maxY)
            y = maxY;

        super.move(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this solution.  I've seen the same behavior in the past and I prefer to just limit the movement of the title window.  You can do the same with resizing as well.

Comment: +1 for this solution as well. I've used something almost exactly like this on past projects myself.

Answer (score 1):

This function is called on move event of titlewindow:

```
        protected function titlewindow1_moveHandler(event:MoveEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var window:UIComponent = event.currentTarget as UIComponent;
            var application:UIComponent = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as UIComponent;
            var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, application.width, application.height);
            var windowBounds:Rectangle = window.getBounds(application);
            var x:Number;
            var y:Number;
            if (windowBounds.left <= bounds.left)
                x = bounds.left;
            else if (windowBounds.right >= bounds.right)
                x = bounds.right - window.width;
            else
                x = window.x;
            if (windowBounds.top <= bounds.top)
                y = bounds.top;
            else if (windowBounds.bottom >= bounds.bottom)
                y = bounds.bottom - window.height;
            else
                y = window.y;
            window.move(x, y);
        }
```